# Whats wrong in this code? im trying to make a login page

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a login page, but it keeps saying username and password not found even though I have entered correct info from the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $errMsg = '';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username == '')
        $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';

    if($password == '')
        $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';

    if($errMsg == ''){
        $conn=new PDO("mysql:host:localhost;dbname=database",'root','');
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM  admin WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($stmt) > 0 && password_verify($password, $stmt['password'])){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $stmt['username'];
            header('location:welcome.php');
            exit;
        }else{
            $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the entire code including with the html and form?

Comment: What does query return? Does `password_verify` return true?

Comment: <html>
<head><title>Login Page</title></head>
<body>
 
   <?php
    if(isset($errMsg)){
     echo $errMsg;
    }
   ?>
   Login
   
    <form action="" method="post">
     <label>Username  :</label><input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
     <label>Password  :</label><input type="password" name="password"/><br/><br />
     <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" class='submit'/><br />
    </form>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: what function is used to save the value into `password` field?

Comment: Your PDO connection string looks to have a problem, try `host=localhost`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but still didnt work, Turns out my query isnt returning anything

Comment: so, how do save the password into `admin` table? `what function is used to save the value into password field?`

Comment: Maybe not the answer to solve the question but your **Concatenation assignment .=** is assigning a variable to a string? why? why not **=** for *$errmsg*

Comment: I manually created a database and inside table admin i gave username root and password root 36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you had said: *"I manually created a database and inside table admin i gave username root and password root 36"*
`password_verify` function verifies that a password matches a **hash**.
But you are passing in a string as the second argument of `password_verify` function. That's why it doesn't find matches.
You should save password into `admin` table as a hash using `password_hash` function:

```
// saving password
password_hash("root 36", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

...
// verifying password
...
if(count($stmt) > 0 && password_verify($password, $stmt['password'])){
...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: thank you so much, that solved it, i've been at it for hours.